# How to use asdf as root user?

Tags: asdf-vm

I need to read some hardware data with privileges permissions, so I need to use the asdf plugin as root. How can I do that?

I tried to start the root user `sudo su` but I cannot access asdf

Answer (score 10):

tl;dr: `sudo -E su`

The problem is that `sudo` doesn't preserve (most) environment variables by default. For `asdf`, the environment variables `ASDF_CONFIG_FILE`, `ASDF_DATA_DIR`, and `ASDF_DIR` are all important, along with the usual suspects, like `PATH`.

Fortunately, we can instruct `sudo` to keep all the environment variables around. From `man sudo`:

> -E, --preserve-env
>
> Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables.  The security policy may return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

---

Resources:

- An [asdf issue comment](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/98#issuecomment-371440554) from anandumdas

Comment: Doesn't work for me, maybe this answer is outdated? Commands like `npm` still aren't found this way.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer on this post pointed me in the right direction: `sudo -E` is required in order to carry over environment variables (including the important `PATH`) into the sudo shell.

However, I was still getting the `unknown command: THECOMMAND. Perhaps you have to reshim?`. What worked for me is getting the path to both the command you want to run and the binary you want to run it through.

In my case, I was trying to use the `hostile` host management tool. It failed because it couldn't find `node`. By specifying both the full `node` path and the direct path to the `hostile` script I was able to get around the reshim errors.

```
sudo -E `asdf which node` `asdf which hostile` load the_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
sudo -E $(which asdf) list
```

or in fish

```
sudo -E (which asdf) list
```

Replace `asdf` with needed asdf plugin, and put the command argument afterwards, like `list` above

Answer (score 0):

Check where your bins are (e.g. `which iex`), in my case

```
/home/<user>/.asdf/shims/
```

Become root bringing the user env with you

```
sudo -Es
```

Export the shims (as pointed by the error)

```
export PATH=/home/riccardo/.asdf/shims/:$PATH
```

You are good to go :thumbup: